# Overwriting email-header.php in my wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I've made a change to email-header.php file so I created a new directory and file...

my_theme/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-header.php

I've made my changes to the file but my site isn't picking it up, it's still using the default woocommerce template.

Does anyone know how to force woocommerce to use my new file?

Comment: In title u mentioned as email_header.php but in your path u mentioned as email-header.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is simply wrong… instead of:

```
my_theme/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-header.php
```

It has to be *(without "templates" subfolder)*:

```
my_theme/woocommerce/emails/email-header.php
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)